# Visual Studio npm Task Runner with Babili

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, browserify, babeljs, task-runner-explorer

I am currently trying to get [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to run when I build my Visual Studio node.js project. I am currently using the Visual Studio Extension [npm task runner](https://github.com/madskristensen/NpmTaskRunner) to execute them both from the CLI. Both seem to work fine when executed like this:

```
browserify ./src/main.js -s test -o ./output.js -t [ babelify --no-comments --minified --compact ]
```

or like this:

```
browserify ./src/main.js -s test -o ./output.js
babel ./output.js -o ./output.min.js --no-comments --minified --compact
```

However if I try to add any [minify plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/minify-mangle-names/) or the [babili](https://babeljs.io/blog/2016/08/30/babili) preset like below, I get this error:

```
> cmd.exe /c npm run compacttest --color=always
> project1@0.0.0 compacttest C:\Projects\Project1\Project1
> browserify ./src/main.js -s test -o ./output.js
Process terminated with code 0.
> cmd.exe /c npm run build --color=always
> project1@0.0.0 build C:\Projects\Project1\Project1
> babel ./output.js -o ./output.min.js --no-comments --minified --compact --presets babili
C:\Projects\Project1\Project1\node_modules\babel-plugin-minify-dead-code-elimination\lib\index.js:21
    ExpressionStatement(path) {
                       ^
Process terminated with code 1.
```

Note that the above commands actually work just fine when run from CLI directly. They only throw this error when run from Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer.

Is the task runner running the scripts at a lower javascript version where the format used in the minify plugins isn't supported or am I just missing something?